# Пожалуйста, поясните что такое RTE?

Tags: python

Прохожу тестирование и есть такой код:

```
a = {'jack': 4098, 'sjoerd': 4127}
b = {4098: 'jack', 4127: 'sjoerd'}
print(a > b)
```

К нему вопрос:
Что будет результатом выполнения кода?

Варианты:

1. RTE
2. True
3. None
4. False

Варианты 2, 3 и 4 - понятны, но что означает RTE?

Comment: данный код выбросит exception: `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'`  - дальше уже решайте сами как эту ошибку сократить в "RTE" ;)

Comment: Runtime Error (ошибка времени выполнения)

Comment: выбирайте: https://www.acronymfinder.com/RTE.html :-D

Comment: Да, судя по контексту имеется в виду `RunTime Error`